# Testing Create Action in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, rspec

Testing Rails 4 Application with RSpec 3 throws an Argument Error (2 for 0) when running a test on posts#create.

My controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@post,
                  :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @post,
                  :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @post.errors,
                  :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
```

My Routes:

```
resources :posts
```

My Test:

```
describe 'POST posts#create' do
  it 'allows admin to create a new post' do
    sign_out user
    sign_in admin
    post :create, post: { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' }
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

The problem is on the `post :create...` line of the controller test.  I'm unsure of why it is not running correctly.  Solutions I have attempted:

**1** `post :create, post: title: 'Title', body: 'Body'`

Thinking there was something wrong about my syntax. This however, throws an error.

**2** `post :create, { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' }`

I thought that the post might be implicit since it is the name of the controller. No dice.

**3** `post :create, post:(post_params)`

Again, I thought that because I have set up the usual permitted params, that they would be necessary. Not surprisingly, the test doesn't have post_params in its current scope.

**4** `post :create, post: { admin: { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' } }`

I had before read that you have to pass in the user creating the post item. Incorrect.

**5** `post :create=> { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' }`

I thought it might be the case that posting implicitly creates a post because that is the controller. However, it returns the argument error.

**6** `post :post=> { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' }`

Finally, I thought that I have to post a new post a give the parameters without having to use the create action.

**Edit - 7** `post(:create, post: { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' })`

After reviewing the API docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html), I thought this would work but it's still the same argument error.

**8**

```
describe 'POST admin#create' do
  it 'allows admin to create a new post' do
    sign_in admin
    expect{
      post :create, post: {title: 'Title', body: 'Body' }
    }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

I attempted to use expect as a block thinking that it would pick up the arguments. Nope.

**Compromise Solution**

```
describe 'POST admin#create' do
  it 'allows admin to create a new post' do
    sign_in admin
    expect{
      Post.create({title: 'Title', body: 'Body' })
    }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

I think the name of the action being the name of the controller threw RSpec off.  So, instead I just manually created a post.  Probably not the recommended solution.

None of these worked.  What am I missing?

**Error Output**

```
 Failure/Error: post(:create, post: { title: 'Title', body: 'Body' })
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
 # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:101:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have also taken off all of my `before_filters` in order to see if that was the problem, however, it gives the same error.

Comment: Can you show the actual error output?

Comment: I see. It's coming from inside the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. It would look like this:

```
describe 'POST admin#create' do
  it 'allows admin to create a new post' do
    sign_out user
    sign_in admin
    post(:create, {post: {title: 'Title', body: 'Body'}})
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

...but the parens and outer curlys are optional.

The error is not coming from your test. The error occurs *during* the post to `:create`. It is coming *from* inside the controller or the model during the `:create` request.

Comment: I have a half-way solution which is just to call `Post.create` which isn't very good but that's what I've come up with.